# Google analytics tracking code revenue issue

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce

The problem is that Revenue shows 0 instead `1.98`. Below is picture of back-end in thank you page. As you can see, `1.98` total is there but in analytics revenue shows `0` instead `1.98`.

[image]

Do you have any idea why this happens ?

Comment: Are you sure you are including this bit?

`(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();`

Comment: Joe Law -- Yes that code is there